# Is there any Settings to Enble the compression of DB size in 64-bit mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am using 64-bit MongoDB and I had done testing with 64-bit MongoDB. The testing details are as follows:

1. I gave one million files as backup to my server using mongodb as my Database Storage.
2. My backup data size is "22.8-GB".
3. The mongodb size is "1.95GB".

Are there any settings available to compress the DB-Size before configuring the backup to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such compression option.

You may run --repair on the database in order to shrink if (if there is something to shrink).
Otherwise apply the standard compression tools on the backup files..

Comment: Hi Andreas Jung,I am very excited to see you reply.I really appreciate you,but running repair would be for repairing the database right?It would not compress the MongoDB size right?

Comment: I said: --repair *shrinks* (if there is something to shrink) it but won't *compress* it.